# Inside spring-boot--application.yml- how to use special character #

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

Yaml file using # sign as comment

## Comments in YAML look like this.

```
################
# SCALAR TYPES #
###############
```

Now inside properties file i have following value

> root#

as password but yaml file using as comment , how can i skip it.

```
spring:
   #data source connection
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vaquarkhan
    username: rootadmin
    password: root#
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The list of special characters in YAML must be escaped.

```
:, {, }, [, ], ,, &, *, #, ?, |, -, <, >, =, !, %, @, `
```

You may either quote the string

```
"root#"
```

or use back slash.

```
root\#
```

Comment: Back slash doesn't work as expected. it leaves backslash in prop value. both "(double quote) & ' (single quote) works

Answer (score 12):

I think you can use quotation marks:

```
spring:
   #data source connection
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vaquarkhan
    username: rootadmin
    password: 'root#'
```

Comment: @PeteT's answer did not work, it leaves the backslash in, this one does.

Answer (score 2):

This could be best way to do it.

```
  spring:
      #data source connection
        datasource:
          url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vaquarkhan
          username: rootadmin
          password: 'root#'
```